# Checking if one of the fields in one of the indexes is null

Tags: javascript

I have the following strcuture:

```
{
  "subs": [
    {
      "status": "1",
      "run_settings": null,
      "ward": "/asda/asd/ada"
      "value": null,
      "name": null
    },
    {
      "status": "0",
      "run_settings": null,
      "ward": "/asda/asd/txa"
      "value": null,
      "name": abc
    }
  ],
  "name": "step"
}
```

I want to check if one of the fields of one of the indexes of the array `subs` is `null`.
So I wrote the following code:

```
this.data.subs.map(sub => Object.values(sub).every(x => (x !== null && x !== 'undefined')))
```

But I get `[false,false]`. I could add another iteration and check if at least one of the values is `false` but I feel like it could be done in a much simpler manner. Please suggest a better way to check if one of the fields of one of the indexes of the array `subs` is `null`.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of Array.every .

Comment: Maybe you want this: `this.data.subs.some(o => Object.values(o).some(v => v === null));`. But try including the expected output to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to get the desired result.

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

```js
const data = {
  "subs": [{
      "status": "1",
      "run_settings": null,
      "ward": "/asda/asd/ada",
      "value": null,
      "name": null
    },
    {
      "status": "0",
      "run_settings": null,
      "ward": "/asda/asd/txa",
      "value": null,
      "name": 'abc'
    }
  ],
  "name": "step"
};


const res = data.subs.some(sub =>
  Object.values(sub).every(x => (x !== null && typeof x !== 'undefined')));

console.log(res);
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: `'undefined' !== undefined` Please remove `'`s.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that